# IIS instances sharing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I don't know if this is common or something but I wanted to check.  So I am building a site on an iis7 server and coming across a weird problem.  Whenever I have 2 clients accessing the site it seems they are sharing info.  Here is an example, when one client does a search for a particular item, the other client goes to the search page and see's the results of client's one search results.  I am using a global class to store this information on my code behind.

So here is my question, my understanding of servers was that if two clients accessed the server they were running on different instances of the site, meaning that even if I have a global class in my code it would be as if two machines were running it.  Am I wrong in this understanding?

Also are there settings in IIS that I need to change for this to work?

Comment: What do you mean by global class? Is there any way of the server knowing 2 different people are accessing it? You should be using Sessions or http get/post for carrying data across pages.

Comment: Sorry I am new to server environments, what do you mean by sessions?

Comment: I am correct in assuming these will not be able to be referenced by another session correct?  Sorry if its a dumb question just trying to figure this all out

Comment: Yep that's correct. I'll move this into an 'answer' so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net, you can use Session variables which are unique serialized token type things stored in server memory. You can store html form info in these sessions so another page on your site can read it.

The syntax in your MVC controller action to create a Session would be:

```
Session["MyFormData"] = someObject;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx